# Standalone PHP script using Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine

Is there a way to make a script where I can do stuff like `$this->EE->db` (i.e. using Expression Engine's classes, for example to access the database), but that can be run in the command line?

I tried searching for it, but the docs don't seem to contain this information (please [correct me if I'm wrong](http://agentdir.com/development/)). I'm using EE 2.4 (the link above should point to 2.4 docs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following article seems to have a possible approach: [Bootstrapping EE for CLI Access](http://www.thenerdary.net/post/20965500651/bootstrapping-ee-for-cli-access)

> - Duplicate your index.php file and name it cli.php.
> - Move the index.php file outside your DOCUMENT_ROOT. Now, technically, this isn’t required, but there’s no reason for prying
>     eyes to see your hard work so why not protect it.
> - Inside cli.php update the $system_path on line 26 to point to your system folder.
> - Inside cli.php update the $routing['controller'] on line 96 to be cli.
> - Inside cli.php update the APPPATH on line 96 to be $system_path.'cli/'.
> - Duplicate the system/expressionengine directory and name it system/cli.
> - Duplicate the cli/controllers/ee.php file and name it cli/controllers/cli.php.
> - Finally, update the class name in cli/controllers/cli.php to be Cli and remove the methods.
> - By default EE calls the index method, so add in an index method to do what you need.

Comment: Really useful! I included the important bits here for future reference (it's better to do that instead of just linking to a URL that may or may not exist in the future). Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2):

@Zenbuman This was useful as a starting point although I would add I had issues with all of my requests going to cli -> index, whereas I wanted some that went to cli->task1, cli->task2 etc

I had to update **system\codeigniter\system\core\URI.php**so that it knew how to extract the parameters I was passing via the command line, I got the code below from a more recent version of Codeigniter which supports the CLI

```
// Is the request coming from the command line?
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli' or defined('STDIN'))
{
    $this->_set_uri_string($this->_parse_cli_args());
    return;
}

// Let's try the REQUEST_URI first, this will work in most situations
```

and also created the function in the same file

```
private function _parse_cli_args()
{
    $args = array_slice($_SERVER['argv'], 1);

    return $args ? '/' . implode('/', $args) : '';
}
```

Also had to comment out the following in my cli.php file as all routing was going to the index method in my cli controller and ignoring my parameters

```
/*
 *  ~ line 109 - 111 /cli.php
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Disable all routing, send everything to the frontend
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$routing['directory'] = '';
$routing['controller'] = 'cli';
//$routing['function'] = '';
```

Even leaving

```
$routing['function'] = '';
```

Will force requests to go to index controller

In the end I felt this was a bit hacky but I really need to use the EE API library in my case. Otherwise I would have just created a separate application with Codeigniter to handle my CLI needs, hope the above helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I found @Zenbuman's answer after solving my own variation of this problem.  My example allows you to keep the cron script inside a module, so if you need your module to have a cron feature it all stays neatly packaged together. [Here's a detailed guide on my blog](http://doingisknowing.blogspot.com.au/2015/08/cron-jobs-using-expressionengine-2.html).