# Programmatically Exporting Content from Expression Engine 2.0

Tags: php, expressionengine

I've inherited an **old** Expression Engine site.  As best I can tell it's version 2.0, the main `index.php`. mainly due to information in the `index.php docblock.

```
/**
 * ExpressionEngine - by EllisLab
 *
 * @package     ExpressionEngine
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2003 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://expressionengine.com
 * @since       Version 2.0
 */
```

Are there any known techniques (or even tools) that would allow me to programmatically export the site's content (along with all the meta/category information) into a neutral format?

My normal approach would be to write a command line script and use [their API](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/), but the [instructions I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570255/standalone-php-script-using-expression-engine) are referring to content that's not present in my version, and some some reason calls to `$ php index.php` are being swallowed silently with no error (which, of course, is impossible — but I haven't had time to dig into it yet)

(New to EE, but not new to programming, so apologies if this an obvious thing)

Comment: Alan- you might have better luck with this over on expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This extension is commercial, but it does exactly what you want:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/export-it

If you want to export the data yourself, it's as easy as using the channel entries module to create your own export templates.

For example:

```
<blog_posts>
    {exp:channel:entries channel='blog'}
        <post>
            <title>{title}</title>
            <blog_article>{blog_article}</blog_article>
        </post>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</blog_posts>
```